how do I stop airplane mode from randomly activating
I'm running ubuntu on a jp X360 laptop. Airplane mode keeps activating on its own - is there a way to block it?
It doesn't get stuck on like all the other peoples problems that I've seen, I've tried the rfkill list and neither are blocked (soft or hard)

I feel like the question as is is missing many fundamental details like 'what OS' and such. rfkill hints at linux, but information on OS/version and hardware seems essential here. Consider what someone trying to help you will need to know and edit in that information for the best chance of finding an answer

im running ubuntu 24.04 on a hp x360 laptop (i5)

You should be including that in your question.
